# mdadm: Win7-install created a boot partition on one of my RAID6 drives. How to rebuild?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, hard-drive-recovery, mdadm

My problem happened when I attempted to install Windows 7 on it's own SSD. The Linux OS I used which has knowledge of the software RAID system is on a SSD that I disconnected prior to the install. This was so that windows (or I) wouldn't inadvertently mess it up.

However, and in retrospect, foolishly, I left the RAID disks connected, thinking that windows wouldn't be so ridiculous as to mess with a HDD that it sees as just unallocated space.

Boy was I wrong! After copying over the installation files to the SSD (as expected and desired), it also created an `ntfs` partition on one of the RAID disks. Both unexpected and totally undesired! [image: screenshot of ntfs partition on raid disk]
    .

I changed out the `SSD`s again, and booted up in linux. `mdadm` didn't seem to have any problem assembling the array as before, but if I tried to mount the array, I got the error message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

`dmesg`:

```
EXT4-fs (md0): ext4_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 0 not in group (block 1318081259)!
EXT4-fs (md0): group descriptors corrupted!
```

I then used `qparted` to delete the newly created `ntfs` partition on `/dev/sdd` so that it matched the other three `/dev/sd{b,c,e}`, and requested a resync of my array with `echo repair > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action`

This took around 4 hours, and upon completion, `dmesg` reports:

```
md: md0: requested-resync done.
```

A bit brief after a 4-hour task, though I'm unsure as to where other log files exist (I also seem to have messed up my sendmail configuration). In any case: No change reported according to `mdadm`, everything checks out.
`mdadm -D /dev/md0` still reports:

```
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed May 23 22:18:45 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 3907026848 (3726.03 GiB 4000.80 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953513424 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon May 26 12:41:58 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 4K

           Name : okamilinkun:0
           UUID : 0c97ebf3:098864d8:126f44e3:e4337102
         Events : 423

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
       3       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde
```

Trying to mount it still reports:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

and `dmesg`:

```
EXT4-fs (md0): ext4_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 0 not in group (block 1318081259)!
EXT4-fs (md0): group descriptors corrupted!
```

I'm a bit unsure where to proceed from here, and trying stuff "to see if it works" is a bit too risky for me. This is what I suggest I should attempt to do:

Tell `mdadm` that `/dev/sdd` (the one that windows wrote into) isn't reliable anymore, pretend it is newly re-introduced to the array, and reconstruct its content based on the other three drives.

I also could be totally wrong in my assumptions, that the creation of the `ntfs` partition on `/dev/sdd` and subsequent deletion has changed something that cannot be fixed this way.

---

**My question:** *Help, what should I do? If I should do what I suggested , how do I do that? From reading documentation, etc, I would think maybe:*

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --set-faulty /dev/sdd
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdd
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --re-add /dev/sdd
```

However, the documentation examples suggest `/dev/sdd1`, which seems strange to me, as there is no partition there as far as linux is concerned, just unallocated space. Maybe these commands won't work without.

Maybe it makes sense to mirror the partition table of one of the other raid devices that weren't touched, before `--re-add`. Something like:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sdd
```

**Bonus question:** *Why would the Windows 7 installation do something so st...potentially dangerous?*

---

### Update

I went ahead and marked `/dev/sdd` as faulty, and removed it (not physically) from the array:

```
# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --set-faulty /dev/sdd
# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdd
```

However, attempting to --re-add was disallowed:

```
# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --re-add /dev/sdd
mdadm: --re-add for /dev/sdd to /dev/md0 is not possible
```

`--add`, was fine.

```
# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdd
```

`mdadm -D /dev/md0` now reports the state as `clean, degraded, recovering`, and `/dev/sdd` as `spare rebuilding`.

`/proc/mdstat` shows the recovery progress:

```
md0 : active raid6 sdd[4] sdc[1] sde[3] sdb[0]
      3907026848 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 4k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [UU_U]
      [>....................]  recovery =  2.1% (42887780/1953513424) finish=348.7min speed=91297K/sec
```

`nmon` also shows expected output:

```
│sdb        0%   87.3    0.0|  >                                              |│
│sdc       71%  109.1    0.0|RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR           > |│
│sdd       40%    0.0   87.3|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW           >                 |│
│sde        0%   87.3    0.0|>                                                ||
```

It looks good so far. Crossing my fingers for another five+ hours :)

---

### Update 2

The recovery of `/dev/sdd` finished, with `dmesg` output:

```
[44972.599552] md: md0: recovery done.
[44972.682811] RAID conf printout:
[44972.682815]  --- level:6 rd:4 wd:4
[44972.682817]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdb
[44972.682819]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdc
[44972.682820]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdd
[44972.682821]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sde
```

Attempting `mount /dev/md0` reports:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

And on `dmesg`:

```
[44984.159908] EXT4-fs (md0): ext4_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 0 not in group (block 1318081259)!
[44984.159912] EXT4-fs (md0): group descriptors corrupted!
```

I'm not sure what do do now. Suggestions?

---

Output of `dumpe2fs /dev/md0`:

```
dumpe2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
Filesystem volume name:   Atlas
Last mounted on:          /mnt/atlas
Filesystem UUID:          e7bfb6a4-c907-4aa0-9b55-9528817bfd70
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              244195328
Block count:              976756712
Reserved block count:     48837835
Free blocks:              92000180
Free inodes:              243414877
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      791
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
RAID stripe width:        2
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Thu May 24 07:22:41 2012
Last mount time:          Sun May 25 23:44:38 2014
Last write time:          Sun May 25 23:46:42 2014
Mount count:              341
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu May 24 07:22:41 2012
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          4357 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      e177a374-0b90-4eaa-b78f-d734aae13051
Journal backup:           inode blocks
dumpe2fs: Corrupt extent header while reading journal super block
```

Comment: The answer to your bonus question is basically, because Windows has never played particularly nice with other OSes on the same system.

Comment: Do you have, or can you get, enough disk space to make a full sector-by-sector copy of all devices that make up your RAID6 array? In order to set aside at least what you have now so that you can experiment without risking further damage.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That's what I thought. It still boggles my mind, since it very easily could have created the boot partition on the drive I requested the install on. Doing it on unallocated space would cause a "no bootable device" waiting to happen if ever the drive was re-purposed.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling No, I wish I did, and I probably should have that kind of backup in place. It's 8 TB of data after all. I have partial backup of the content though, but only the crucial stuff. There is still a lot of things I would be quite sad to lose.

Comment: I don't remember where, and I can't really search for it now, but I know I've seen something about using device *overlays* (by some term) to have all writes going to some place other than the actual device you're reading most of the data from. Maybe that is worth spending some minutes searching for. Your maybe commands seem about right; you're using the whole device, not a partition, to back your RAID array, so that should be what's needed. However, I would feel much better trying it if there was a way to get back to the present state (it's broken, but hopefully not *too* broken).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, I decided to go ahead with doing a complete disk recovery on `/dev/sdd`. It look good so far, thanks for the quick response so far. See update for details, if of interest.

Comment: If this works for you, please remember to write up a proper self-answer and accept it for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That would be my intention yes :)

Comment: For the future, install Windows first. Always. Linux almost always detects Windows boot loaders anyways. If you can't install Windows first, disconnect all other hard drives first (as you mentioned already)

Comment: From the outputs you gave, `mdadm` seems to see the raid array as OK.
Could you also add the output of the 
`sfdisk -d /dev/sd?`
and `cat /proc/mdadm` commands ?

May be working at the partition level on the array would also help:
 `fsck /dev/md0`

Comment: It's been 3 years since this issue occurred, and since reset the whole array, so I unfortunately won't be able to give you the output of those commands. However, perhaps nice for other people to that come across this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit surprised that `mdadm` assembled the array using that disk in the first place, but this is another story. Unfortunately, your array is probably no more in a recoverable state.

The Linux software raid assumes that the array is healthy (clean), unless a read or write error is signaled by the disk controller, as explained on the [Linux raid wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Detecting,_querying_and_testing#Detecting_a_drive_failure#).
The driver assumes that because there is a lot of [redundant data stored on the disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Error_rates_and_handling), and the link between the hard disk and the controller also uses error detection.

So four your situation (in RAID6 mode) the parity blocks are not even read.

[image: Raid6]

Overwriting one of your disk was (in the point of view of the disk) a perfectly valid request and was completed by your disk without error.

Now when you requested an array rebuild using a disk with corrupted data, you just spread corruped data all over your array.

The right think to do was to set the drive faulty, then add it back to the array. The array would have been rebuilt in a safe state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer pim. Indeed, which is useful to know for later. The biggest mistake I made was to not test my backup until it mattered. Backup 101, in hindsight.